# AWS Lambda Function Not Executing All Python Code But Not Receiving An Error Either

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

First, thanks for all the support I've gotten on this, I feel like I'm near the home-stretch on this. But I have another question on AWS Lambda.

I'm writing a Lambda Function that processes csv from an intake bucket and then returns four different processed files to different destination buckets for each of the different transformations.

I do **not** get any error messages, and the files are sent to the destination buckets properly labeled; however, most of the code is not being executed so almost none of the transformations are taking place.

**edit**
The exception is the function "**newstage**" which creates a new column/feature engineering, and having that apply within the Lambda function itself, **and** everything in the first output as well. Along with creating a new column, it also changes zero values to NaN's and just noticed that that was done too.

So it seems that it's continually putting that output down from `df1` data and the issue might be with `df1.to_csv(csv_buffer)` and not updating to `df2.to_csv... df3.to_csv...` as per new object/data subset when it's downloading to the subsequent buckets.

What am I missing or need to change to invoke the rest of the code and have it perform the respective transformations?

```
#trying a different approach to importing data into Lambad
import boto3
import io 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime 
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
csv_buffer = StringIO()

#creating the export buckets
bucket1 = 'random-processed-salestotal'
bucket2 = 'random-processed-winlossgrouped'
bucket3 = 'random-employees-stagetotal'
bucket4 = 'random-employees-salespivot'

csv_file_1 = 'total_sales_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'
csv_file_2 = 'stages_grouped_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'
csv_file_3 = 'employee_stage_totals_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'
csv_file_4 = 'employee_pivot_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'

def newstage(x):
    """Creating a function that simplifies and condenses the Stage column into 3 types"""
    if x in 'Closed Won':
         return "won"
    elif x in list(['01 Pending','01 Qualified Opportunity','02 Consideration','02 Proposal','03 Negotiation','03 Proposal','04 Contracts','04 Validation',
    '05 Negotiation','06 Contracts','Hold - Re-engage','Hold - Stalled']):
        return "in pipeline"
    else:
        return "lost"


def featureengineering(event, context):
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_file_name =  event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    read_file = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=s3_file_name)
   
    #turning the CSV into a dataframe in AWS Lambda
    s3_data = io.BytesIO(read_file.get('Body').read())
    df = pd.read_csv(s3_data, encoding="ISO-8859-1")

    #replacing erroneous zero values to nan (missing) which is more accurate and a general table,
    #and creating a new column with just three stages instead for simplification
    df[['Company Annual Revenue','Number of Employees']] = df[['Company Annual Revenue','Number of Employees']].replace(0,np.nan)
    df['WonLossProgress'] = df.Stage.apply(newstage)
    df1 = df
    df1.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    s3_resource.Object(bucket1, csv_file_1).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())


    #creating a groupby of the 3 major pipeline components and exporting that
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('WonLossProgress')['Opportunity Amount'].agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.std, np.ma.count])).astype(int)
    df2.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    s3_resource.Object(bucket2, csv_file_2).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())

    #creating export for employee performance
    EmployeesOutcome = pd.crosstab(df.WonLossProgress, df['Sales Person'], dropna=False)
    EmployeesOutcome = EmployeesOutcome.T
    EmployeesOutcome.reset_index(inplace = True)
    EmployeesOutcome['Win/Loss Ratio'] = EmployeesOutcome.won / EmployeesOutcome.lost
    EmployeesOutcome.sort_values('in pipeline', ascending=False)
    df3 = EmployeesOutcome
    df3.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    s3_resource.Object(bucket3, csv_file_3).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())

    #creating a pivot table of opportunity amount per stage per employee
    table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Opportunity Amount', index=['Sales Person'], columns=['WonLossProgress'], aggfunc=np.sum).sort_values('in pipeline', ascending=False)
    table[['in pipeline','lost','won']] = table[['in pipeline','lost','won']].replace(np.nan,0)
    df4 = EmployeesOutcome
    df4.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    s3_resource.Object(bucket4, csv_file_4).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

**edit** This fixed it. It's not pretty, but it works

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

csv_buffer1 = StringIO()
csv_buffer2 = StringIO()
csv_buffer3 = StringIO()
csv_buffer4 = StringIO()

#creating the export buckets
bucket1 = 'proficio-processed-salestotal'
bucket2 = 'proficio-processed-winlossgrouped'
bucket3 = 'proficio-employees-stagetotal'
bucket4 = 'proficio-employees-salespivot'

csv_file_1 = 'total_sales_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'
csv_file_2 = 'stages_grouped_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'
csv_file_3 = 'employee_stage_totals_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'
csv_file_4 = 'employee_pivot_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'

def newstage(x):
    """Creating a function that simplifies and condenses the Stage column into 3 types"""
    if x in 'Closed Won':
         return "won"
    elif x in list(['01 Pending','01 Qualified Opportunity','02 Consideration','02 Proposal','03 Negotiation','03 Proposal','04 Contracts','04 Validation',
    '05 Negotiation','06 Contracts','Hold - Re-engage','Hold - Stalled']):
        return "in pipeline"
    else:
        return "lost"


def featureengineering(event, context):
```

As was noted, instantiating it outside the function worked, and I did them separately just to be sure. That made them data subsets go to their proper, respective buckets.

Comment: Do the CloudWatch logs say anything? A timeout perhaps?

Comment: It's actually executing "correctly" and placing files in the respective S3 buckets and even correctly labelling/naming them, BUT the data is not transformed as it should be. It's like only the function newstage is being applied to the data, but then everything is just being passed. Cloudwatch Logs does not indicate a problem.

Comment: Do you have a sample event?

Comment: The event object? ie the raw csv file to be transformed? Unfortunately I cant post that publicly itself.

Comment: It might be something to do with context cache (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html) - `Objects declared outside of the function's handler method remain initialized`... may be try running the function from Lambda console with the expected `event` source to see if it makes any difference. You may want to update function before each execution just so it creates a new context env